# codecs.open is taking a long time to execute

Tags: python, python-2.7

I found that `codecs.open` takes a long time to execute in Python 2.x (approximately 5.9s).

Is there is any way to change my code below to so that it will execute faster?

```
with codecs.open(file,encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore', mode="r") as curr_file:
    for line in curr_file.readlines():
```

Comment: `codes.open` is taking more time than what? And, how are you measuring it? FYI, `codes.open()`, with the args you've listed above, takes about 4.5 microseconds on ,my PC as compared to `open()`, which takes about 2 microseconds. I measured in `ipython`, using `%timeit codecs.open('/etc/passwd', encoding='utf-8', errors='ignore', mode='r').close()`

Comment: Is it actually taking `codecs.open` that long, or is it taking that long to open *and* iterate over the lines in the file? Your title  suggests you're only talking about `codecs.open`, but you're asking for feedback on both lines of code, which includes iterating over the file.

Comment: And how big is the file, both in terms of number of lines and file size on disk?

Comment: during iterate over the lines in the file is taking more time I am worrying about once codecs open readlines will take more time since am not familiar in python

Comment: each file contains request and response xml

Comment: below lines will read and write the lines if line.find("<soapenv:Envelope") != -1 or line.find("</soapenv:Envelope") != -1 :
        i=i+1
       if (i == 1):
        file_i = codecs.open(inputFolder_new+"/"+filename,encoding='utf-8', mode="a")
        file_i.writelines(line)